# How to transpile harmony for server side react rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ecmascript-6, babeljs, react-rails

I am using `react-rails`, and I'm trying to render server side using the `prerender` option:

```
<%= react_component('MyComponent', @data, {prerender: true}) %>
```

When I do this, I get an error as a result of `const`:

```
Exception: SyntaxError: Unexpected keyword 'const'. Const declarations are not supported in strict mode.
```

The `const` keyword, IIUC, is available in ES6, so it needs to be transpiled in some way. I'm trying to figure out how to tell react-rails to transpile the ES6. It seems like `config.react.jsx_transform_options` is the way to specify, it, but I've added the following to application.rb and it does not have any effect:

application.rb:

```
config.react.jsx_transform_options = {
  whitelist: [
    "es6.constants",
  ],
}
```

What am I doing wrong here?